# Necessity of hypothesis in distance from a set in an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In Kreyzig's Functional Analysis book, one theorem in inner product spaces is about the existence and uniqueness of a minimal point from a set.

> **3.3-1 Theorem (Minimizing vector)**.  Let $X$ be an inner product space and $M\ne\varnothing$ a convex subset which is complete (in the metric induced by the inner product).  Then for every given $x\in X$ there exists a unique $y\in M$ such that $\delta=\inf_{\widetilde{y}\in M}||x-\widetilde{y}||=||x-y||$.

First, the hypothesis of convexity is obviously necessary for the proof of uniqueness.  (A counterexample would be a circle.)  Is it also necessary for the proof of existence?  I feel that completeness of $M$ should be enough but am unable to find a counterexample.

That is, I am looking for a space where $M$ is not convex but is complete and yet the $y$ mentioned in the theorem does not exist.

Second, is it necessary that the space be an inner product space and not merely a normed space?  I confess I have not thought about the second question as much but any replies to either question will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with complete orthonormal set $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Define a curve $C(t)$ on $[1,\infty)$ in such a way that for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$,
$$
     C(t)=(1+2^{-t})\left[\cos(\pi (t-n)/2)e_{n}+\sin(\pi (t-n)/2)e_{n+1}\right],
                \;\;\; n \le t \le n+1.
$$
Then $\|C(t)\|=(1+2^{-t})$ for all $t \ge 1$, and
$$
             \|e_{0}-C(t)\|^{2}=1+\|C(t)\|^{2}
$$
satisfies $\inf_{t \ge 1}\|e_{0}-C(t)\|=2$, a value which is not achieved for any $t \in [1,\infty)$. So there is no closest point to $e_{0}$ on the curve $C$.

The image of the curve $C$ is a complete subset of $H$ because (a) $[1,\infty)$ is a complete subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and (b) $\{ C(t_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence iff $\{ t_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of such a point holds for closed subsets of complete metric spaces. If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space, $F\subset X$ a closed subset and $y\in X$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $F$ such that $d(x_n,y)\rightarrow d(y,F)$. You can use the triangle equality to show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence the limit $x$ exists and $x\in F$, since $F$ is closed. The continuity if the distance function guarantees $d(x,y)=d(y,F)$.

**Edit:** You'd need $F$ to be compact, since $(x_n)$ isn't necessarily Cauchy. In an inner product space this can be shown, but not for arbitrary metric spaces.

Comment: Oops, the triangle equality doesn't work the way I thought. You need some form of compactness here.

Comment: I'm not sure about your reasoning... Let X = [-2, 2] and F = [-2,1] U [1,2] and x_n = (-1)^n *(n+1)/n. Then d(x_n, 0) -> d(0, F), but x_n is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @iolo yeah I noticed that. You need some form of compactness.